# Selenium (python) crashes when sending keys with virtual display

Tags: python, selenium

I'm running some stuff that necessitates browser automation on an AWS instance. I'm trying to run Selenium with a virtual display, but my code crashes whenever I try to use Selenium to send keyboard input to a page. I can download source code and locate elements on pages, but not use the send_keys method. Below is an MWE reproducing the crash:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1920, 1080))
display.start()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://google.com")

search_field = driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
search_field.send_keys("foo")
```

And here's a stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mwe.py", line 12, in <module>
    search_field.send_keys(u"foo")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.62)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320),platform=Linux 4.4.0-116-generic x86_64)
```

My Google Fu has failed me thus far, so any input is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please update your Chrome driver to 2.39. Your version 2.27 is very old and incompatible with Chrome version.